# remove files after x hours but ignore hidden folder/files

Tags: deleted-files

I have a mounted a folder to a seedbox. and in the folder i use syncthing. so it creates a  " .stfolder" which is used for syncthing .  basically i am having trouble finding a  script to run that says look in x folder and xx subfolders but ignore hidden folder and delete everything that is older than xxx hours.

I tried to modify " find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} ; "  but had no success it kept finding the hidden folder

folder structure is like this
`downloads/Movies/.stfolder` and `downloads/TV/.stfolder`  with `TV` and `Movies` having files and subfolders

Ultimately i am running this on a raspberry pi4. and my intent is to use a cron job to call a script to run every 12 hours or so  . i have my seed box mounted to my rasperrypi 4 using curlftpfs

Any solution that works would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Note that "raspberry pi4" only identifies the hardware. What operating system is running on that machine would be a more useful information.

Answer (score 0):

```
LC_ALL=C find /path/to/files/ -name '.*' -prune -o \
  -mtime +5 -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

Would delete the regular files in and below the `/path/to/files` directory that have not been modified in the last 6 (not 5) days ignoring hidden ones (including the ones in hidden directories that are pruned from the directory tree `find` descends in).

If it's just the `.stfolder` directories you want to skip, you can do:

```
find /path/to/files/ -name .stfolder -type d -prune -o \
  -mtime +5 -type f -exec rm -f {} +
```

(in that case the `LC_ALL=C` is not necessary as that's only to work around the fact that `*` doesn't match across non-characters in some `find` implementations).

With `zsh`, you can just do:

```
rm -f /path/to/files/**/*(.m+5)
```

As hidden dirs / files are skipped by default.

Or for all old files except those in or below `.stfolder` directories:

```
set -o extendedglob # best in ~/.zshrc
rm -f /path/to/files/(^.stfolder/)#*(D.m+5)
```

(where `D` disables the skipping of hidden files / directories, and `(^.stfolder)#` matches any number of subdirectories other than those called `.stfolder`).